# Priority order of activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have two activities with same intent filters. than which one will start first? 
I have two activity **activity1.java** and **activity2.java**
then which activity starts first?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this out, though my guess is the android os should prompt you with a dialog to choose one of the two Activities. This is similar to when you click on a music file and you are prompted with different media/music players on your device that are capable of playing the file.(they have intent filters)

Answer (score 0):

The Android usually shows up a dialog for you choose which one you want. Like the image below:

[image]